# convert LocalDateTime to Date by using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, date, java-8, java-time

I have a `java.time.LocalDateTime` and i want to convert it in `java.util.Date`

```kotlin
val myLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(5)
```

I want to convert `LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(5)` to `java.util.Date` in kotlin.

How Can i do it?

Comment: Are you needing an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` for a legacy API that you cannot upgrade just now? I think it’s the only case where you should touch the `Date` class.

Comment: `Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(5).toInstant())`. Do not use `LocalDateTime`. For your old-fashioned `Date` you need a point in time, and `LocalDateTime` cannot give you that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mandatory information in order to make a `LocalDateTime` convertable to a `java.util.Date`…

Before you try, think about if you can use `Instant.now()`, because the methods for legacy compatibility require `Instant`s as arguments:

```
fun main() {
    // get "now" as Instant
    val now = Instant.now()
    // print the java.util.Date created from the Instant
    println(Date.from(now))
    // use the Instant plus 5 days to create another date
    val date = Date.from(now.plus(5, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
    // create a formatter for the Date
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    // and print it using the formatter
    println(formatter.format(date))
}
```

Output (some moments ago on my middle-european machine):

```
Thu Feb 09 15:31:06 CET 2023
2023-02-14
```

If you really need to use a `LocalDateTime`, which has no zone or offset, you will have to add one, convert the result (a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`) `toInstant()` and create `Date`s `from` those…

---

If it's all about dates (year, month of year, day of month) without time of day, you could simply use a `java.time.LocalDate`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // get "today" as LocalDate
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    // print it using toString() implicitly
    println(today)
    // add five days
    val fiveDaysLater = today.plusDays(5)
    // and print it formatted by a prebuilt formatter
    println(fiveDaysLater.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
}
```

Output:

```
2023-02-10
2023-02-15
```

Comment: hi @deHaar How do I convert this date to a Date format like: yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Do you have to format the `Date` or any other datetime object (e.g. the `LocalDateTime` or `Instant`?

Comment: *How do I convert this date to a Date format like: yyyy-MM-dd* You cannot. A `Date` cannot have a format. If you need a particular format, use a `String` and forget about the old and poorly designed `Date` class.